# Postgres storing multiple IDs

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm starting to design a big project - similar to Facebook. I got into a situation where I need to solve the following problem.

When you take Facebook at Posting choose who can see the post. (You can check friend who can see the post, I need work with this friends)

And I do not want to deal with similar style

Very bad way (way of example only)

```
post_id | visible_user_ id 
5       | 15,25,156,489,21,56,41,56,21,56,1465 ...
```

This method would be good but the table could have millions of records

```
post_id | visible_user_id 
5       | 15 
5       | 25 
5       | 156
```

The question is: which way do I move in or do not have experience with something similar? I want to find fastest solution, what do you think about serialized string?

Comment: Normalize your database. Serialized values in the DB should be your absolute last resort. PostgreSQL arrays can be OK if you need them to save disk space, but have trade-offs too.

Answer (score 2):

Serialized string with all ids is a very bad idea

Why?

Well, in this string you will have all the ids of every user that can see the post right? If you remove one of them, then you need to recover again all the friends of that user in order to update that field right? too much work to remove one user, and the same if you want to add another user (one more friend)

Another thing , that field type should be of type `TEXT` in order to store users with lots of friends.

In a first look i can tell you how i'll do it:

First, i will make for tables, `users`, `users_friends`, `posts` and `users_posts`

- **users**: user_id
- **users_friends**: user_id, friend_id (friend_id will be a foreign key of the users table)
- **posts**: post_id, post_visualization
- **users_posts**: user_id, post_id

With this four tables you will solve that problem:

1. An user register in your site => insert into `users` table
2. An user add one friend => afaik the friend should be in your `users` table, so insert in the `users_friends` table with the id of the user and the id of the friend
3. An user makes one post only for friends => Then insert into posts with value FRIENDS (for example) in post_visualization field.
4. You want to know all the post that should see one friend => join the four tables and you will get that value
5. Remove one friend => Delete from table `users_friends`

I think this should give you an idea to start with your project, so good luck

If anything is unclear just comment it

Comment: The only issue here is Pg's huge 28 byte row overhead. If they're dealing with "millions" of entries...

Comment: What is the difference between your way and the second example that I wrote ? ("This method would be good but the table could have millions of records")

Comment: There's no difference, no matter the table have millions of records, is all about normalization.